# In python, how would you stipulate that each list of lists has length = 1?

Tags: python

How would you rewrite the following python code in one line?

```
def check_list_size(list1):
    for lst in list1:
        if len(lst) != 1:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `all`:

```
def check_list_size(list1):
   return all(len(i) == 1 for i in list1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
all(len(lst) == 1 for lst in lists)
```